# Has anyone had success debugging a MikroE EasyMx board using the STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, mikroc, stm32f1

I have recently bought a MikroE EasyMx Pro v7 board for the STM32 MCU, however, the compiler which MikroE uses for Arm Development is their proprietary MikroC compiler, which has hardly any tutorials on it.

I was wondering if anyone has successfully configured their board and the STM32Cube IDE to work well together, or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the MCU is from STM32 series, you can use STM32CubeIDE to develop for it. This applies to any board.

Also, as described in the [manual](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/full-featured-boards/easy/easymx-pro-v7-stm32/easymx-pro-v7-stm32-manual-v102.pdf), the onboard programmer is based on ST-Link V2, so debugging should not be any issue.

Comment: I can program the MCU using the STM32Cube IDE, however when I try to debug it, I says something like "connection failed"